# How can I ignore extra fields with JSR 303?

Tags: java, rest, validation, annotations, jsr

I'm getting a JSON response in a RESTful endpoint. The fields in the response are variable. In particular some fields that I do not care about them.
Because of some requirements I have to use JSR 303 validation annotation to an envelope class to handle the response.

The body of the response is like:

`{
  "parameter1":"val1",
  "parameter2":"val2",
  "optional_parameter":"valopt",
  "not_important_list":["v1","v2","v3"]
}`

My class is like:

```
public class MessageEnvelope {
    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    public final String parameter1;

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    public final String parameter2;

    //the rest of the fields should be ignored
}
```

I receive mapping error because of the the extra fields. How can I ignore the extra fields that I do not care about them?

Comment: The mapping error sounds like it's in the JSON -> Object library you're using (e.g. Jackson, GSON). I don't think it's related to validation. I'm most familiar with Jackson and there are some straight forward ways to tell it to ignore unrecognized fields seen in JSON.

Comment: Correct. This comment helped me to figure out the issue. In my case the deserialization is done with Jackson and I could ignore them with `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)` annotation before the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

The mapping error was actually in the JSON -> Object library. In this case "Jackson".

I could solve that with the `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)` annotation before the class definition.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class MessageEnvelope { 
    ...
}
```